# Htaccess Redirect all subpages from domain.co.uk/* to just domain.co.uk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently in a weird situation in regards to a complex hosting setup [Which cannot be altered].

I got one website hosted called domain.com and i got another domain which links to that same hosting `domain.co.uk`. But `domain.co.uk` is redirecting to a folder called `/redirect` on `domain.com`. So when you open `domain.co.uk`, you get the content of domain.com/redirect showing up (which is perfect.).

However, i am getting an internal error on everything after that domain, e.g. domain.co.uk/blah returns an internal error.

I am trying to get every subpages or user entries will redirect to domain.co.uk

This is what i have tried:

`RewriteRule ^domain.co.uk/(.*) http://domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]`

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)com.*
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.co.uk? [L,R=301]
```

or

`RewriteRule ^domain.co.uk/(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk [R=301,NC,L]`

Still getting an interal error.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Still getting an internal server error on subpages.

Comment: Did you clear your cache or test with other browser ?

Comment: Yes, still the same issue. -  `This web page has a redirect loop`

Comment: Just tried it again, the www version of the domain.co.uk now works but the subpages now lead to a internal error

Comment: The problem is not in my .htaccess. you have another problem that you need to solve. Redirecting you request seems not to be the solution.